# Is there a backup program for the Siemens Gigaset SL400?

Tags: google-sync, google-contacts

I would like to synchronize my Google account with my Siemens Gigaset SL400. Is that possible?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, they interface with my computer. Where would you advice me to ask?

Comment: "The spacious address book" ... "These can be synchronised with Outlook". The question you should probably be asking is probably "How can I sync my Google account with Outlook" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This app](http://www.gigaset.com/hq_en/cms/home/support/support/downloads/quicksync/quicksync-for-windows.html) from Gigaset.com claims to be able do so:

> **Gigaset QuickSync for Windows**
>
> The new Gigaset phones let you exchange your contact data both quickly and easily. Plus, you can sync your address book data. Gigaset QuickSync for fast and easy synchronization of your PC address book with your Gigaset phone.
>
> NEW: Cloud synchronisation with Google™ contacts.
>
> Thanks to this convenient software, you can easily synchronize your addresses in Google™ contacts, Microsoft® Outlook®, Windows® contacts (Windows® Vista, Windows® 7 or Windows® 8) with your Gigaset phone via Bluetooth®, a data transfer cable or Ethernet network connection.